# MouseMove on a external applet

Tags: java, mousemove

I'm trying to get the mouse move event from external applet that has been called like this:

```
Applet loader = (Applet) new URLClassLoader(
            new URL[] { new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "aoo.jar").toURL() }).loadClass("class").newInstance();
        loader.setStub(this);
        loader.init();
                    loader.addMouseMotionListener(a);
                    loader.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(788, 560));
                    loader.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(788, 560));
```

But for some reason the mouse event listener doesnt work.
Is there any way to capture the mouse move event from the external animated applet?

```
                    getContentPane().removeAll();
        getContentPane().add(loader, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        getContentPane().add(jt, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

This is my jframe content pane is it helps.

Thank you

Comment: *"applet that has been called like this:"*  Why was the applet called that way?   What is calling it?  Another applet, a frame, a ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally events in AWT don't bubble up. (In fact mouse events have a bizarre behaviour where they do bubble up iff there are no mouse listeners on the child component.) Generally the way to hack this sort of thing is with a "glass pane" (google it), or you can use an `AWTEventListener` on the `Toolkit`.

Comment: I'm tring to use AWTEvent but how can i set it to only the applet not the the whole program?

Comment: No, it'll apply to the whole "AppContext", although you can look at the event and see what component it is over. (It's all a hack, anyway.)